# C# compare multiple textbox values

Tags: c#, textbox, compare

So I'm having 4 different text boxes, each one can accept only 1 character. This values need to be different, so what is the shortest code to do this, I also need to know/remember which text boxes have same value so I can set error provider on them.

Comparing each one to another is not an option.

Comment: Show what have you tried, are you stuck some where ? Do you have any code in place to start the problem ? Otherwise we can't help you doing your *homework*.

Comment: I don't see how any solution will avoid comparing each value to each other value.

Comment: I do not have anything yet, I would just need logic not the code. Yes you need to compare it somehow, I was thinking about loop but not sure how to remember textbox with same value then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<TextBox> myTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

//Add your textboxes to the list here...

var distinctBoxes = myTextBoxes.GroupBy(t=>T.Text);
if(distinctBoxes.Count() == 4)
{
    //All values are distinct
}
else
{
    foreach(var g in distinctBoxes.Where(g=>g.Count() > 1))
    {
        //These are the duplicate boxes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's awfully hard to do what you are describing without comparing each one to another, so here is a quick and easy way to check if there are any duplicates.

```
 public void Foo()
 {
    string[] allTextBoxes = { textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text }; // Put textboxes into an array.
    if (allTextBoxes.Distinct().Count() != allTextBoxes.Count()) // Check if the string has any duplicates.
    {
            // Do some code.
    }
 }
```